# Dynamically updating [checked] in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-pipe

**componentA.ts**:

```
@Input() array;

<input type="checkbox" [checked]="array | contains: value"/>
<label>{{array.length}}</label>
```

**componentB.ts**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-b',
  templateUrl: './app.component-b.html'
})
export class AppComponentB {
  array = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

I update `array` in some other components. While the `label` updates the array's length correctly, the check box doesn't seem to be updated. `contains` is just a simple pipe that checks if `value` is part of `array`. I put a `console.log` in the `contains` pipe and only got the output when the page renders at first, not when `array` is changed. Why is this?

Thanks..

Comment: Can you show where exactly array is defined? is it in service or component?

Comment: It's just a variable in a component. I added some code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because if you use `push` to add new item to array then the array reference isn't changed while pure pipe will be executed only when it detects a pure change to the input value (`array` and `value` in your case)

There is two solutions:

1) return new array

```
this.array = this.array.concat(4)
```

or

```
this.array = [...this.array, 4];
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HAmtpEJj5BqgRoSISTW6?p=preview)**

2) use impure pipe

```
@Pipe({name: 'contains', pure: false})
export class ContainsPipe implements PipeTransform {
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UsEUIqnLjMOFU8Lwj4jg?p=preview)**

For more details see also

- [NgFor doesn't update data with Pipe in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456430/ngfor-doesnt-update-data-with-pipe-in-angular2)
- [Unraveling Angular 2 book, Chapter 1, Example 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757603/unraveling-angular-2-book-chapter-1-example-5/39761822)
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: Thanks! That was it.