# Angular 2 - *ngFor with keys pipe is not refreshed when object is changed

Tags: angular

I'm using keys pipe in *ngfor loop. Data are fed in JSON.

```
    @Pipe({
      name: 'keys'
    })
    export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value, args: string[]): any {
        if (!value) {
          return value;
        }

        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
          keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
        }
        return keys;
      }
   }
```

--

```
<div *ngFor="let item of jsonObject | keys">
        <p>{{ item.value.code }}</p>
</div>
```

The problem is when I delete on of the element in JSON, ngFor is not updated.

I have tried two option already:

- calling ***this.applicationRef.tick();*** after element delete, no change
- impure pipe "***pure: false***". This caused enormous memory usage in chrome in hundreds of MBs and I had to kill the process.

If there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way which you can try:

```
delete(id) {
  this.jsonObject = this.jsonObject.filter(x => x.id !== id);
}
```

This way you won't mutate the original array. That's crutial thing for pipe

See also

- [NgFor doesn't update data with Pipe in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456430/ngfor-doesnt-update-data-with-pipe-in-angular2/34497504#34497504)
- [Unraveling Angular 2 book, Chapter 1, Example 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757603/unraveling-angular-2-book-chapter-1-example-5/39761822#39761822)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I have filtered the object by key name and used filter & reduce. Actual code is here if anyone is interested: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbxOeG

Answer (score 5):

**Pure** pipes dont run unless the reference or value is changed. To fix this add `pure: false` to your Pipe decorator. See [Pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#pure-and-impure-pipes)

ex.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'keyVal',
    pure: false
})
export class KeyValPipe implements PipeTransform {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT** I didnt see that the OP had already done this. Another option is to set a temp variable and then assign jsonObject to it thus creating a new reference. You could also try a deep copy from temp to jsonObject

Comment: OP said `This caused enormous memory usage in chrome in hundreds of MBs and I had to kill the process. `

Comment: Woops, thats my bad