# How to force Angular 2 change detection when value in the form model updates?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Alright, let me start with describing the problem I am actually trying to solve.

I need my form model to have the this structure:

```
{
  nested: {
    first: 'one',
    second: 'two',
    third: 'three',
    forth: 'four', ...
  }, ...
}
```

The child properties will be added to the model dynamically based on the users input, and the number of nested levels can vary.

The implementation looks something like this:

**Initialize form:**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    nested: this.getControls() // of type FormGroup
  });
}
```

**Load controls:**

```
getControls(): FormGroup {
  let group: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  Object.keys(this.controls).forEach((key) => {
    let control: FormControl = new FormControl(this.controls[key]);
    group.addControl(key, control);
  })
  return group
}
```

**Template with *ngFor:**

```
<div *ngFor="let control of form.get('nested').controls | keys; let i = index">
  <label>{{ getLabel(i) }}</label>
  <input [attr.placeholder]="control.value">
</div>
```

**With an add new control method:**

```
addControl(key, value) {
  let control: FormControl = new FormControl(value)
  this.form.get('nested').addControl(key, control);
  this.cdf.detectChanges();
}
```

A stripped down implementation available on [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/kvv2ez22zUuLyAoQG9mK/)

Now, the problem I have is that the values updates for the model but the template is not re-rendering with the added inputs.

I have tried to force the change detection to fire but it has not worked.

I understand that using `FormArray` provides more dynamic features, but it produces an output as this:

```
{
  nested: [
    { first: 'one' },
    { second: 'two' },
    { third: 'three' },
    { forth: 'four' }, ...
  ], ...
}
```

Which brings us back to source of the problem.

Of course, I could utilize a function which transform back the model to the desired format before I push it on to the database, but given that the model could have several different properties at different levels in the tree, whereas for some I might be displayed as arrays and some might not, things can easily get overly complex.

Which leaves me with `FormGroup`, *but then how do I make sure the template renders as new input is applied?* Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer you the following solutions:

1) Using [impure pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#impure-pipes)

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'keys',
  pure: false
})
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/rOu34w97mJUO3cs67Zm3?p=preview)**

2) Passing new reference after adding control

```
addControl(key, value) {
  this.controls[key] = value;
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    nested: this.getControls()
  });
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/LQhEtQ1ewZKZcWk3A0X4?p=preview)**

---

I also removed `getLabel` function and added mapping control name to your pipe

```
keyArr.forEach((key) => {
   value[key].name = key;
   dataArr.push(value[key])
})
```

See also

- [Unraveling Angular 2 book, Chapter 1, Example 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757603/unraveling-angular-2-book-chapter-1-example-5/39761822#39761822)
- [NgFor doesn't update data with Pipe in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456430/ngfor-doesnt-update-data-with-pipe-in-angular2)

Comment: Alright! I never suspected the pipe, will definitely investigate further on pure vs. impure pipes. Perfect answer.